# Capturing a stream from a canvas, requestFrame won't work unless the canvas has changed. What is a fast way to make an invisible change to a canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, web-mediarecorder, requestframe

requestFrame will not add a frame to the MediaRecorder stream unless the canvas has changed. I have several unchanged frames in a row that I want in my video, so I think I need to trick requestFrame into thinking the canvas has changed. What's a simple, performant way to do this?